# Why could not app get http response from server? It works with wife but not with 3G?

Tags: android, android-widget, http-post, http-proxy

I am tryin to write a app that post the incoming phone number and get response and show the result by using toast to the screen. it works with wife in emulator and phone but not with 3G. When call ended, toast shows result. I have already changed the APN to the internet but it does not work. Is there a way to do this with 3G?

### BroadCastReceiver

```
if(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING.equals(state)) {

            incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER); 

            if   (!client.contactExists(context, incomingNumber)){

            try {

             String response=client.login5(incomingNumber,hash);
            JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject(response);
        resusername = jObject.getString("name");
         reshash = jObject.getString("hash");



         Toast a=  Toast.makeText(context,"\n"+"Telefon Numarası:" + incomingNumber+"\n"+"Adına Kayıtlı Kişi:" +  resusername+"\n", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
         a.setGravity(Gravity.TOP|Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
         a.show();



        //   msg += "My phone number:" +  client.getMy10DigitPhoneNumber()+"\n";            

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
      /*  if(reshash==hash && frame.konrolnum(incomingNumber)!=true) {
        msg+="User name is: "+resusername;
        frame.createContact(resusername, incomingNumber);}*/


        } }
```

### Httpclient

```
public String login5(String tlf,String hash) {      
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 

    InputStream is = null;
     String result = "";
     ArrayList<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

     try 
     { 


           HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
           HttpProtocolParams.setUseExpectContinue(httpclient.getParams(), false);
           HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://www.whois118.com/broadcast.php");
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("telefon",tlf));
           nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("hash", hash));
           httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
           HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
           HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

           is = entity.getContent();

      }

      catch (Exception e)
      {
       Log.e("log_tag", "Error in http connection " + e.toString());
      }
  // convert response to string
      try 
      {
           BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( is, "UTF-8"), 8);
           StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
           String line = null;

       while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) 
       {
           sb.append(line + "\n");
       }

        is.close();
        result = sb.toString();



       Log.v("log","Result :"+result);
  } 
  catch (Exception e)
  {
   Log.v("log", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
  }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: +1 for the epic typography in title (works with Wife, not with 3G) :) :) Ain't your wife connected? ;) -> WiFi is what you meant (by the way, I am not a native English speaker either, no offense intented, just a nice typography that made me laugh)

Comment: I have added the permision to the manifest file..

Comment: +1 for the epic typo too! :)

Comment: In english, "wife" is the woman you are married to. The word you actually need to use here is "WIFI" which means a wireless network. That said, it is indeed often a problem to get a wife connection, they ain't easy to connect to, let alone understanding how they work internally

Comment: I have to work with 3G :) Because people can not find every where wifi connection. The app can not work without internet connection

Comment: Sorry for my poor English :)

Comment: Does it really work with wife? That would be a publishable first.

Comment: Yes , that is really funny :) İs there anyone who can give me information about my question ?